# Server sessions with Thinktecture Identity Server 3

Tags: identityserver3

Can I use server sessions with Id. Srv. 3 at all?

As Thinktecture Id. Srv. 3 uses cookie authentication middleware for the authentication sessions, I have tried this by implementing IAuthenticationSessionStore and using the implementation in app.UseCookieAuthentication() as described here :

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/05/11/owin-protocol-middleware-cookies-and-reference-mode-sessions-we-need-your-feedback/

and here :

https://gist.github.com/vibronet/90d4646c273930ff12d4

Have done in the start-up this before app.UseIdentityServer() as below :

app.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
         SessionStore = 
         ... (an instance of IAuthenticationSessionStore implementation)

app.UseIdentityServer(options);

where options is an IdentityServerOptions object.

However, I can login from an app. (using this server) and no implemented method of IAuthenticationSessionStore gets called.

So, is it possible to implement server sessions with Id. Srv. 3 with the above interface (with some modifications?) or is there any other way to do this please. Or is it not possible at all?

**UPDATE - About what we are trying to achieve :**

We have multiple apps. using an identity server 3 implementation for open id authentication.

**Goals :**

**1. Cross-app consistent session sliding expiration.** So, whenever a user visits a page on any of the apps., their session must be renewed across all apps. 
Presently, there is inconsistency regarding this across apps., as the sliding expiration only renews the user's session for that app.

**2. Reduce the size of browser cookie.** We are having multiple custom claims from each app being added, making the payload on each request heavy.

**3. Cross-app session control.** We want to be able to kick a user out of all apps. (possibly on all of their devices)

Any help would be really appreciated.